# iOS application crash randomly on ogg vorbis library

Tags: ios, iphone, ogg

I have implemented and am running OGG vorbis library to play .ogg format audio files using the library given [here](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer).. but the problem is that at any point it gives this exception and crashes the application,

```
 -[IDZAQAudioPlayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Where as I am running my project under ARC…

Any help regarding this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your audio player as a property if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I already have set its property as `@property(nonatomic, strong) id <IDZAudioPlayer> player`

Comment: In that case you need to post more code before anyone can help you.

Comment: Em using an ogg vorbis library from [here](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZAQAudioPlayer) …